# Predicting Network traffic by datamining

Tags: bigdata, prediction

I want to create a model to predict network traffic, there are 3 kinds of Traffic EF( sensitive to Delay), AF( less sensitive to delay) and BE( not sensitive). Now I want to Predict these Traffic for the next cycle based on the incoming traffic in Previous Cycles, I have enough data to analyze, but Don't have any Idea which model should I use( knn, neural network ....) My field is not big data but I really need to create this model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the best model, you would first have to train the data. I believe your current data have a true label, right? Keep it first.

Then, split your data into 70% and 30%. Predict the label of your 70% by applying the various models (Artificial Neural Networks, Bayesian etc).

Then, train your remaining 30% on this model to get the predicted label.

After that, use the predicted label of this remaining 30% data and compare with the true label of your 100%.

Then, do a confusion matrix. The best algorithm would be the one with the highest accuracy.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Just to add on, different classification method suits different data set. Hence, my advice is to conduct the experiment above to find the best model or if you would like to save time, you could cite the previous researches that have been conducted.